# How to use customized describe function with a grouping variable to get statistics by group?

Tags: python, pandas, describe

I was trying to get descriptive stats for a particular variable, by a grouping variable. I wanted more percentile values in the output than the describe function gives by default.

I tried the following code:

`df.groupby('city')['population'].describe([0.01,0.05,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.99])`

It gives an error:
`describe() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do -- calling the function properly

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].describe(percentiles=[0.01,0.05,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.99])
```